# Optimization and printing values from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, optimization

I have a NxM Matrix that is encoded in 0s and 1s in random indexes in the matrix (1 represents a pixel to be painted and 0s are blank spaces). I would like to group all the ones in a dictionary and print them as one command instead of separate iterations for optimization purposes, and then put it back into the original matrix to create its final shape (of a tetris game).

The Matrix looks like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

My code is as follows:

```
def solution(imat, painter):
   nrows, ncols = imat.shape # gets the shape of the matrix (20 rows and 20 columns)
   start = 0
   end = 0
   rows = dict.fromkeys(range(nrows), []) #creates the dictionary
   for r in range(nrows): # loops through the number of rows
      for c in range(ncols): # loops through the number of columns
          if imat[r,c] == 1: # checks if at a specific index there exists a 1
             rows[r].append((r,c)) # if so it appends it to the dictionary
              painter.paint('square', r, c, 1) # prints the 1s, but as individuals instead of a block.
```

I am able to append the dictionary with all the 1s, but unable to make all the 1s as one object and put back into the original matrix (that being the `imat.shape`)

The final output should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS6oY.png), with as little commands as possible.

Additional information can be found: [here](https://gist.github.com/PrathamPatel/db928dd70b53189239b8e9cecd21d1b7)

All help and advice will be highly appreciated

Comment: "I would like to group all the ones in a dictionary and print them as one command instead of separate iterations for optimization purposes" not quite sure how that is an optimization. To build the dictionary you need to look at all the elements and that's N^2 if I remember correctly adding an item to a dictionary is NlogN

Comment: I don't really understand the point either. Why is the dictionary better? The data seems quite easy to compress, if you're worried about memory footprint.

Comment: The goal is to basically print the matrix with as little instructions as possible - instead of printing it by searching at every iteration which is one command every time, I want to print it in chunks - which I am not quite sure on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a sample example for a naive compression algorithm. The idea is to count how many `0`s and `1`s come in a row. Worst case scenario you get no compression at all, but your data seems to be quite grouped and so in general you should see quite some reduction.

I also added an example on how you can print this data, as it seems to be what you want in the end. Change the `print_block` method to use whatever thing you use to draw the screen -- I show you here how you can use it to print 'in blocks' the compressed data.

```
m = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

def compress(mat):
    """ Compress each row by counting how many 0's and 1's are in a row.

        Example:
            1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
            0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
        Result
            0 2 2 3 1
            4 1 1 2
    """ 
    nm = []
    for r in mat:
        nr = []
        gather = 0
        acc = 0
        for c in r:
            if c == gather: 
                acc += 1
            else:
                nr.append(acc)
                gather = int(not gather)
                acc = 1
        nr.append(acc)
        nm.append(nr)
    return nm

print_calls = 0
def print_block(value, nbr):
    global print_calls 
    print_calls += 1
    for i in range(nbr):
        print(value, end=" ")

def print_compressed(mat):
    for r_block in mat:
        for i, nbr in enumerate(r_block):
            print_block(i % 2, nbr) # change this line to draw your actual board
        print()

cm = compress(m)
print_compressed(cm)
print('print_calls =', print_calls)
```

This outputs for me

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
print_calls = 70
```

The reduction of print calls is from 20*20 = 400 -> 70. That is, a reduction by 82.5%.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it really helps. Appreciate it.

Comment: is there a way to only compress the 1s in a new matrix, by excluding all the 0s?

Comment: I can't imagine that it would help you in any way. If you want remove the draw calls for 0's, just don't call the `print_block` function for those values.